# What does it mean if a simple linear neural network performs better than an LSTM on sequential data?

Tags: neural-networks, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, genetics, sequence-analysis

I'm working on a genetic data project, where one data sample is represented as sequences of integers (of length 2000) and it needs to be classified into one of 4 classes, so I guess it is similar to timeseries. For the project, I built a simple 3-layer linear neural network and a 3-layer LSTM model. I expected the LSTM to outperform the MLP, since the data is sequential and it might therefore be able to pick up on information the MLP can not. However, the LSTM has lousy performance, while the MLP is able to get up to 90 percent test accuracy.

Right now I'm just wondering how this might be explained. I figured that maybe the sequences were too long for the LSTM to process them properly, so I performed feature selection and halved the length of the sequences. This improved things slightly, but the MLP is still ways better. Could it be that I need to reduce the features even further? Or can anyone provide some insight into why the LSTM performs so much worse than a simple MLP on this case? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What's the number of parameters of both architectures?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Do you mean the total number of trainable parameters? For the neural network this is 150531 and for the LSTM 199555

Comment: I think there might be some disparity in your architectures. The MLP has very narrow layers by the number of parameters you gave, while the LSTM looks very broad (assuming it's input dimension is 3, dummy coding the nucleobases). What are the sizes of the layers?

Comment: The MLP is three layers: input 2000 to hidden 128, hidden 128 to hidden 128 and hidden 128 to output classes 3. The LSTM has input dimension 1 to hidden 128, hidden to hidden 128 and a linear layer from hidden 128 to output 3. This means the LSTM is then quite broad as you say because the sequence length is 2000, if I understand correctly. What exactly do you mean with dummy coding?

Comment: You calculation for the parameter is a bit off, the MLP has 273027 parameters (2001*128 + 129*128 + 129*3). The LSTM has 199555 parameters indeed.

Comment: Well noted! That might be due to my rounding of the sequence length to 2000. Do the parameters tell you something about why the LSTM does not perform as well as the MLP?

Comment: not really, I was expecting a big disparity between model capacity perhaps.

Comment: Notice however that the LSTM imposes constraints in how parameters can be used